# JTable isn't editable after Overriding isCellEditable method in AbstractTableModel class

Tags: java, swing

The `isCellEditable(row, column);` method for my AbstractTableModel is overridden and I have checked that when I click on the cell in question it returns `true` or `false` correctly, however, it is not allowing me to edit the cell:

```
private class KAMModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String[] column = {"Member Number", "Member Name", "Secondary Name", "Address", "Phone", "Tickets"};
    private final Class<?>[] types = {Double.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Integer.class};
    private final boolean[] editable = {false, false, false, false, false, true};
    private ArrayList<Object[]> data;

    // skip other overridden methods
    @Override 
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        System.out.println(editable[column]); // prints correct true/false based on the column
        return editable[column];
    }
}
```

Why would I see that `isCellEditable` is getting fired and is also telling me correctly if my column is editable or not and yet I cannot edit the column. It just highlights the row. The cell is outlined, but I'm not able to edit it.

UPDATE:

Runnable code:

```
package kiss;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class kiss extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private KAMModel kam = new KAMModel();

    public kiss() {
        initComponents();
        kam.search("", "", "", "", "");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(kam);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(kiss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(kiss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(kiss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(kiss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new kiss().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration                   
private class KAMModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String[] column = {"Member Number", "Member Name", "Secondary Name", "Address", "Phone", "Tickets"};
    private final Class<?>[] types = {Double.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Integer.class};
    private final boolean[] editable = {false, false, false, false, false, true};
    private ArrayList<Object[]> data;

    public KAMModel() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data.get(row)[col];
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return column.length;
    }
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return column[i];
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if (data == null) return 0;
        return data.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return types[column].getClass();
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        System.out.println(editable[column]);
        return editable[column];
    }
    public void search(String memberNumber, String acctNumber, String memberName, String phoneNumber, String address) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Object[] {"123456789", "John Smith", "Jane Smith", "123 Main St.", "555-555-1212", ""});
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void fireTableDataChanged() {
        super.fireTableDataChanged();
        resizeColumns();
    }
    public void resizeColumns() {
        float[] percents = {8f, 20f, 20f, 39f, 10f, 3f};
        int tableWidth = jTable1.getWidth();
        TableColumn tc;
        TableColumnModel tcm = jTable1.getColumnModel();
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            tc = tcm.getColumn(x);
            int cwidth = Math.round(percents[x] * tableWidth);
            tc.setPreferredWidth(cwidth);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please could you provide a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy-paste and see what's happening?

Comment: I will need to remove quite a bit of my code to make it runnable. This plugs into a database and is part of a more complex GUI.

Comment: What stops you to remove that code? Make another (simpler) one with the minimum code w/o db calls. Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Your `isCellEditable` looks fine. What happens if you return `true` by default? it allows you to edit all the table? Check it and tell me

Comment: I'm working on it. It's my lunch break

Comment: Added runnable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in the code:

1. You're adding `"123456789"`and `""` in the model, although these values are supposed to be of type Double and Integer
2. You're returning `Class.class` as column class, for every colum. Replace `return types[column].getClass();` by `return types[column];`.

And of course, you forgot to implement `setValueAt()`, so even if the cell is editable, the edited value is not stored in the model.

Comment: Thank you! Why did that fail? I don't understand why the `getcolumnclass(int column)` method makes it not work?

Comment: types[column] contains the right value: Integer.class. But you're not returning that. You're calling getClass() on Integer.class, and returning that. Integer.class is of type Class. So you're returning Class.class instead of Integer.class.

Comment: I understand that I was returning Class.class, but why would that keep it from being editable?

Comment: Because JTable uses what is returned by getColumnClass to choose the appropriate editor: it has one for String, Boolean, Integer, etc., but not for Class.